# Dual/Extended monitors with VGA + HDMI to DVI

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I want to buy two monitors for using with my laptop (without using the laptop's screen)
My laptop has VGA and HDMI outputs.

**1st scenario:**

VGA output of laptop -> VGA input of monitor +

HDMI output of laptop -> HDMI input of another monitor.
I tested extending screens with this scenario and it worked perfectly.

**2nd scenario:**

VGA output of laptop -> VGA input of monitor +

HDMI output of laptop -> HDMI input of HDMI2DVI converter -> DVI output of HDMI2DVI converter -> DVI input of monitor.

---

For the 1st scenario, I have to buy 2 monitors which have HDMI input.

For the 2nd scenario, I can buy 2 monitors which haven't HDMI input (cheaper than 1st scenario, because this type of monitor is cheaper than HDMI monitors).

---

Does the second scenario work? (extended screens, not mirror/same screen)

Comment: I do not quite understand the "For the 1st scenario then i have to buy 2 monitors which have HDMI input."  Are you assuming you need two identical monitors?  (Which is NOT required, aesthetics aside).

Comment: yes, i need two identical monitors.

Comment: To over-simplify, there are two DVI standards: DVI-A (analogue) and DVI-D (digital). I don't know what your converter is, but I suspect it is probably just a cable which connects HDMI to DVI-D. If you buy a monitor without HDMI, it is almost certain that the DVI connector will be DVI-A, so an HDMI to DVI cable will **not** work. See http://www.datapro.net/techinfo/dvi_info.html for more details.

Comment: AFH, he was asking if he could connect the laptop's HDMI output to a DVI monitor's input. There's no analog signal involved here.

Comment: @Arakel - As I understand it, the DVI interface on a monitor without HDMI is DVI-A. It may well plug in, but there will be no analogue signal unless there are electronics in the converter. The reason that monitors without HDMI are cheaper is not the saving on the socket, but the saving on the electronics for the digital input. The cheapest solution will be one monitor with HDMI and one without.

Comment: @AFH, that is certainly not correct. The DVI-A connection is rarer that both DVI-D and DVI-I. Almost all monitors with DVI connector and no HDMI follow the DVI-D standard. And you can easily verify that with a DVI-only monitor, just by connecting it to any graphics card and check the connection type.

Comment: monitor: http://uk.hardware.info/productinfo/210983/acer-k222hqlbd#tab:specifications . It seems like a digital monitor. Wrong?

Comment: The HDCP compatibility implies that it is indeed digital: sorry if I raised a red herring. It leaves me puzzled as to where the saving is when HDMI input is not included - the difference is significant, much more than the cost of wiring up an extra socket. Apologies also to @Arakel, but I don't have a DVI/non-HDMI monitor for testing, so I shall bow to your experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be a problem. HDMI and DVI use the same signal, being that HDMI carries sound and DVI doesn't.

You can confidently buy a DVI monitor.

Comment: thanks, http://www.hepsiburada.com/liste/s-link-slx-240-hdmi-m-to-dvi-241-f-adaptor/productDetails.aspx?productId=bs40838&categoryId=105307&SKU=BS40838 1 question more: I will buy this HDMI2DVI converter. It's okey?

Comment: Yes, that will work perfectly for it.

Comment: This is no longer universally true. HDMI has evolved since. DVI is only compatible with unencrypted HDMI up to version 1.2.

Comment: Daniel, correct me if I'm wrong, but HDMI 1.3 is backward compatible with DVI Single Link and perfectly compatible with DVI Dual Link is it not?

Comment: No, HDMI 1.3 *can* use a higher bandwidth (340 MHz) for higher resolutions (up to 2560x1600@60Hz). This is outside of what DVI specifies and as such not compatible. Of course, both endpoints will negotiate mutually supported features, so higher resolutions will simply not be available for the user to select. So while it will fall back gracefully, saying they “use the same signal” is not really true anymore. HDMI 2.0 pushes the bandwidth even higher, to support 4K.

Comment: But that is what I referred. DVI Dual Link is also capable of 340 MHz of clock frequency and 2560x1600@60Hz. Where's the incompatibility?

Comment: monitor: http://uk.hardware.info/productinfo/210983/acer-k222hqlbd#tab:specifications

Comment: @Musher, that will work without any problem with the setup you described, including the adapter HDMI to DVI.

Comment: @Arakel DVI Dual Link is fundamentally different from HDMI and absolutely incompatible. It doesn’t provide more clock rate but more “width” (as in TMDS pairs). HDMI simply does not have enough pins to support it. Even if your display device were to support Dual Link DVI, an HDMI signal source, even when HDMI-2.0-compatible, would not be able to utilize it and as such will be limited to 1920x1200.

Comment: @Arakel, it is working without any problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

okay here is another adaptor
http://www.indirimvekalite.com/bilgisayar-tablet-k-81/aksesuarlar-k-221/goruntu-kablolari-k-142/s-link-40-metre-vga-data-kablo-m-m-u-1949.html

for your information